# Subtraction and addition of convex polygons

Tags: polygon, addition, subtraction, convex, concave

I have two 2D *convex* polygons. I want to

- ***subtract*** one from the other one and
- ***add*** one to the other one

The resulting polygon must be either *concave* or a - **better** - a set of *convex* polygons (e.g. triangles).

Do you have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Well, i guess these 2 have also the property of sharing at least a piece of an edge, without intersecating each other. If so, edit the question

Comment: I would imagine you'd use [rotating calipers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers). Which is used for union and intersection of convex polygons. The terms should also be useful for finding algorithms.